# My USB mouse can't be configured via the UI (left handed or speed)

Tags: usb, mouse, touchpad, 18.10

Configuring via the UI (settings -> devices -> mouse and touchpad) doesn't apply anything on the following settings:

- primary button
- mouse speed

I have a USB mouse connected to my laptop. Attaching xinput list of touchpad:

```
xinput list-props 21
Device 'PS/2 Generic Mouse':
    Device Enabled (147):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (149): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Product ID (269):    2, 1
    Device Node (270):  "/dev/input/event22"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (281): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (283):  0
    Axis Labels (284):  "Rel X" (157), "Rel Y" (158)
    Button Labels (285):    "Button Left" (150), "Button Middle" (151), "Button Right" (152), "Button Wheel Up" (153), "Button Wheel Down" (154)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (286): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (287):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (288):  50
    Evdev Middle Button Button (289):   2
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (290): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (291): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (292):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (293):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (294):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (295):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (296):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (297):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (298): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (299):  0
```

Attaching xinput list of usb external mouse:

```
xinput list-props 11
Device 'USB OPTICAL MOUSE ':
    Device Enabled (147):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (149): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Product ID (269):    10077, 2601
    Device Node (270):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (281): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (283):  0
    Axis Labels (284):  "Rel X" (157), "Rel Y" (158), "Rel Horiz Wheel" (275), "Rel Vert Wheel" (276)
    Button Labels (285):    "Button Left" (150), "Button Middle" (151), "Button Right" (152), "Button Wheel Up" (153), "Button Wheel Down" (154), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (155), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (156), "Button Side" (273), "Button Extra" (274), "Button Unknown" (272), "Button Unknown" (272), "Button Unknown" (272), "Button Unknown" (272)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (286): 1, 1, 1
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (287):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (288):  50
    Evdev Middle Button Button (289):   2
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (290): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (291): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (292):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (293):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (294):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (295):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (296):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (297):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (298): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (299):  0
```